# Modify string and add new string

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I'm having the string value 740D1E11625C89019E61D0CC I want to insert "-" in string after every count 5 length.

I'm using

```
ReplaceAt(serial, 5, 0, "-");


public static string ReplaceAt(string str, int index, int length, string replace)
        {
            return str.Remove(index, Math.Min(length, str.Length - index))
                    .Insert(index, replace);
        }
```

Result

**740D1-E11625C89019E61D0CC**

It should be

**740D1-E1162-5C890-19E61-D0CC**

Is this right way to modify string ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Batch`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) from [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/). It has a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) as well.

```
var s = "740D1E11625C89019E61D0CC";
var array = s.Batch(5, seq => new string(seq.ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", array));
```

prints

```
740D1-E1162-5C890-19E61-D0CC
```

Comment: You might want to add that answer on the duplicate target. Very nice way to solve this.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think this solution _might_ not be a good answer for the duplicate question because it wants `,` at the end as well but `Batch` does not provide this. `string.Join("-", array) + "-"` will solve this but it will be too custom I think.

Comment: Okay, then +1 will do here :)